# jQuery wildcard selection

Tags: jquery, regex

Suppose you have some `<div>`s:

```
<div id="div_num1"></div>
<div id="div_num2"></div>
<div id="div_num3"></div>
```

You can select all those divs by choosing `$("div[id^='div_num']")`. How can you buld a function that references the number succeeding the prefix?

For example, a function which will alert the number 3 for `"div_num3"`.

More generally, how can you use full-blown regex in jQuery selectors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have the set of elements, you can iterate it and get the number there:

```
$("div[id^='div_num']").each(function() {
    if (this.id.match(/^div_num(\d+)$/)) {
        alert(RegExp.$1);
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks, is there no elegant way to do this?

Comment: @Yuval A: that *is* the elegant way.  You cannot use regexes in jQuery selectors.

Comment: @Yuval A: If you mean elegant way like a selector that is not just used to describe elements properties to select them (that’s what the selector is for). Then no.

Answer (score 1):

It should be something like this:

```
$('div[id^=div_num]').click(function() {
    var m = /div_num(\d+)/.exec($(this).attr('id'));
    if (m == null) // no match
        return;
    alert(m[1]);  // note that the match will be in m[1], not m[0]
}
```